# Compare autoware PCDs

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Howdy,

I recorded multiple datasets using a Velodyne VLP-16 and a Septentrio AsteRx SBi (using serial GNSS/NMEA) and used NDT_Mapping to compute the pointclouds.

I was wondering what the best way to compare multiple pointclouds is, e.g. overlay them to see if maps from different days align or what the differences are.

Is CloudCompare good and if so, do I need to convert the file type?

I was also wondering what the differences between the different methods are, (Pcl_anh, Pcl_generic, Pcl_OpenMP etc. )

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349250/compare-autoware-pcds/) by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2020-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CloudCompare is the way to go. Just save them as .PCD or any format readable from Cloud Compare and enjoy comparing ;)

---

Originally posted by [Albtech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5273/albtech/) with karma: 28 on 2020-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) on 2020-04-17**:
Thank you!